# error message: Incomplete type in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I know there are many similar named questions, but I can't figure out my problem after reading through numbers of them.

I am writing a game for a class project.

In `class Dungeon`, `function monsterTurn()` needs access to `setCurrSp()`which is declared as protected in `class Hero`. Therefore, I tried to add `monsterTurn()` as a friend function to `Hero`.  Since I had `#include "Hero.hpp"`in `class Dungeon`, I used forward declartion, but it throws an error `Incomplete type 'Dungeon' named in nested name specifier`.

I know declare `setCurrSp()` as public will solve all these problems, but I don't feel good to leave a setter public. It seems like leaving a backdoor open for unexpected modify. Correct me if I were wrong on this.

Followed are part of the codes.

Hero.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Entity.hpp"
class Dungeon;

class Hero : public Entity{

protected:
    void setCurrSp(int currSp)              { this->currSp = currSp;}
public:
    friend void Dungeon::monstersTurn(vector<Hero>::iterator hero, vector<Hero> heros);
}
```

Dungeon.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Hero.hpp"
#include "Monster.hpp"
class Dungeon{
public:
    void monstersTurn(vector<Hero>::iterator hero, vector<Hero> heroes);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like __Dungeon.hpp__ has ``class Dungeon`` declared twice: from __Hero.hpp__ and the file itself. Have you tried removing it? And do you have problems with cross-inclusion?

Comment: Do you really need a vector passed by value?

Comment: @Fullfungo isn't it forward declaration? having ``class Dungeon`` before ``class Hero`` 's declaration

Comment: For the friend member function decl. (`friend void Dungeon::monstersTurn()`), a  forward declaration is probably not sufficient. `class Hero` had to know the ful declaration of `class Dungeon`. If you make instead `friend class Dungeon;` (i.e. the whole class), a forward declaration of `class Dungeon` _is_ sufficient.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov hhh, just learned vector a week ago. What will be the more efficient approach? a pointer to the vector?

Comment: If you don't plan to change the vector, the idiomatic approach is to pass by const reference.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you!!! I thought about having a friend class instead of a friend function, but I afraid having a friend class will be too "open" (can't find an appropriate vocab) that lots functions will have access to Hero class. Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: Either you make a complicated re-design which might bother you for other reasons or you live with the fact that your `friend` decl. is a bit "too open". Concerning the latter, I wouldn't justice too hard. Both classes are your own. So, I wouldn't be too paranoid concerning abuse...

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov  My professor would cry if she knew I forgot ``const reference``. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Scheff perhaps, I should pay more attention to UML design or pseudocode, which were suggested by professor, instead of coding right away. You have a good night!!!

Comment: Sometimes, it seems that any good design seems to fail to model the "real" world problem. At one point, you start to make compromises (instead of designing forever). (My sad experience.) - Have a good night too. - In Germany, it's already morning. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `friend` declaration

```
    friend void Dungeon::monstersTurn(vector<Hero>::iterator hero, vector<Hero> heros);
```

the forward declaration

```
class Dungeon;
```

is not sufficient.

Demo:

```
class Dungeon; // forward declaration

class Hero {
  friend void Dungeon::takeHero(Hero&);
};

class Dungeon {
  public:
    void take(Hero&);
};
```

Output:

```
main.cpp:5:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Dungeon'
    4 |   friend void Dungeon::takeHero(Hero&);
      |                                      ^
main.cpp:1:7: note: forward declaration of 'class Dungeon'
    1 | class Dungeon; // forward declaration
      |       ^~~~~~~
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63757cc586fe81f8)

The `class Hero` needs a ful declaration of `class Dungeon` to "know" its members.

For a `friend class` declaration, a forward declaration *is* sufficient:

```
class Dungeon; // forward declaration

class Hero {
  friend class Dungeon;
};

class Dungeon {
  public:
    void take(Hero&);
};
```

Output:

(none) – compiled without complaints

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/089d125c6e4bb050)